# show $f_n = \frac{1}{n} \chi_{[n,\infty]}$ is monotonically decreasing

Tags: measure-theory, real-numbers

How do I show $f_n = \frac{1}{n} \chi_{[n,\infty]}$ is monotonically decreasing?

I know that $\frac{1}{n}$ is monotonically decreasing, but I am unsure how to show $f_n$ is monotonically decreasing because I don't know how to show it is decreasing with the characteristic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient to prove $f_{n+1}\leq f_n$ for each $n$.

Let $x \in \Bbb{R}$, then either $x < n$ or $n \leq x < n+1$ or $n+1\leq x.$

If $x <n$, then $f_n(x)=0=f_{n+1}(x),$

If $n \leq x <n+1$, then $f_{n+1}(x)= 0 < \frac{1}{n}=f_n(x)$ and

if $x \geq n+1$, then $f_{n+1}(x) = \frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{1}{n} = f_n(x).$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Fix some $x\in\mathbb R$ and prove that sequence $(f_n(x))_n$ is monotonically decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $n_{1}<n_{2}$. Then, $[n_{2},\infty] \subset [n_{1},\infty]$. Thus,

\begin{eqnarray}
\chi_{[n_{2},\infty]}(x) \leq \chi_{[n_{1},\infty]}(x)~~~\forall x\in \mathbb{R}.
\end{eqnarray}